# Use relative urls in Joomla menus

Tags: url-rewriting, joomla

I have joomla site which is located in `mydomain.com/somefolder/otherfolder/TheSite`. I have created a rewrite rule to invisibly redirect all requests beginning with `mydomain.com/TheSite` to this url. It works fine.

My problem is that the urls that my menuitems point to are the old `mydomain/somefolder/otherfolder/TheSite/stuff`. If they were relative urls, it would work.

My question: *How can I force joomla to use relative urls for the menuitems, or use the urls I explicitly specify?*

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to make Joomla produce only relative URLs is to edit the core method "_" of the `JRoute` class:

```
JRoute::_()
```

This is called by Joomla application and extensions to generate consistent URLs.

It is found in:

> libraries/joomla/methods.php

Making Joomla spit out relative URLs probably isn't the best way to do it. Making the absolute URLs point correctly would.